# Should I always pass the user password for encryption?

Tags: python, django, encryption, django-rest-framework, cryptography

I'm aware of how encryption works. I'm unable to get my mind around the fact that for generating a key using PBKDF2HMAC, I need the user password for encryption. For example, if a user logs in and creates a note, I want it to be encrypted. The key that is derived shouldn't be stored anywhere. So should I pass the users password every time the user creates a note for it to be encrypted or is there any other way.

Note: By passing the user password, I mean from the frontend to the backend. Also, is it bad practice to store the user password as a django-session variable once it has been passed by the user?

Comment: This is not encryption, it is *hashing*.

Comment: Furthermore using the password for that is *risky*. If the user changes the password, then the notes are no longer readable.

Comment: Could you clarify what are you actually doing? Are we talking about Django user password storage or notes encryption implementation?  The latter probably has nothing to do with Django itself

Comment: If you are trying to create something like LastPass (password manager) then yes, you need to provide the password somehow to the backend but not store it anywhere. Actually, probably you should not even pass the password to the backend and implement all cryptography client-side. It depends on the goals

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov It's just a simple notes app for understanding encryption. I want to encrypt the notes with user password, so that it can be read only by the user. Also for the previous comments, when the user changes the password, one way would be to decrypt with old password and re-encrypt with the new password. So how does any password manager pass the password if they aren't supposed to store the password, the user has to enter the master password everytime he creates a new entry but that isn't the case.

Comment: @Vaibhav I believe they store the password only locally and encrypt everything client-side. Don't know how they store it locally to be safe, probably only in-memory, so when you close the browser the password needs to be re-entered. Maybe, something assymetrical should help in your case. Derive public key from the password when you have it, and use for encryption, but to decrypt - original password will be required.